# Removing first level keys and combining its values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary as follows:

```
{
    'firstA': {0: {'textA': [1, 2, 3]}},
    'firstB': {1: {'textB': [79, 89]}}
}
```

and I am trying to strip/remove the first level keys so that my output will be:

```
{
    0: {'textA': [1, 2, 3]},
    1: {'textB': [79, 89]}
}
```

I checked online where I can try using `dict1.update(dict2)` but this only seems to apply if I only had 2 individual dictionaries to begin with.

While I can use the following:

```
for k, v in my_dictionary:
    print v
```

which seems to returns me what I want but how do I combine/merge them from there? Or when I have more then 2 first-level keys - eg. `firstC...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {'firstA': {0: {'textA': [1, 2, 3]}}, 'firstB': {1: {'textB': [79, 89]}}}
result = {a:b for i in d.values() for a, b in i.items()}
```

Output:

```
{0: {'textA': [1, 2, 3]}, 1: {'textB': [79, 89]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
for i, v in enumerate(d.items()):
    if i==0:
        yourd=v[1]
    else :
        yourd.update(v[1])
yourd
{0: {'textA': [1, 2, 3]}, 1: {'textB': [79, 89]}}
```